# Error 2339 With || and Union Types

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

I've created a sample block of code that shows a syntax error in TypeScript, but runs fine as JavaScript: [TypeScript Sandbox](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=%09class%20Person%20%7B%0A%09%09name%3A%20string%3B%0A%09%09job%3A%20string%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09var%20person1%3APerson%20%3D%20%7Bname%3A%20'hi'%2C%09job%3A%20'yes'%7D%3B%0A%09var%20name%20%3D%20'bye'%3B%0A%09%0A%09function%20showName(person1%3APerson%20%7C%20string%20)%20%7B%0A%09%09var%20personsName%3A%20string%20%3D%20person1.name%20%7C%7C%20person1%3B%0A%09%09%0A%09%09document.write(personsName)%3B%0A%09%09document.write('%3Cbr%20%2F%3E')%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09showName(person1)%3B%0A%09showName(name)%3B%0A)

Basically, when I'm trying to use the `||` (`OR`) operator to collaese an object property that may be `undefined` TypeScript it saying that the property doesn't exist, which I know and is why I'm using `||`.

```
class Person {
    name: string;
    job: string;
}

var person1:Person = {name: 'hi',   job: 'yes'};
var name = 'bye';

function showName(person1:Person | string ) {
    var personsName: string = person1.name || person1;

    document.write(personsName);
    document.write('<br />');
}

showName(person1);
showName(name);
```

The output is exactly as I would expect it to be:

```
hi
bye
```

However, TypeScript shows a syntax error on person1.name. Why? What is the correct TypeScript way of doing this?

Comment: Your code isn't resilient to someone assigning a `name` property to `String.prototype`, or `person1.name` being `""` (in which case you're probably going to see `[Object object]` or something similarly useless). David Sherret's answer is very useful in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a [type guard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/18/what-s-new-in-the-typescript-type-system.aspx):

```
function showName(person1: Person | string) {
    var personsName = (typeof person1 === "string") ? person1 : person1.name;

    document.write(personsName);
    document.write('<br />');
}
```

Note that this code will throw an error when `person1` is `null || undefined`, but so did the original code. There's lots of different ways to handle that so I'll leave it up to you.

Comment: This answer, while not directly answering my question, answers the question I should have asked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to assert the type in your expression, since the operand is of union type. i.e

```
 var personsName: string = (<Person>person1).name || <string>person1;
```

Comment: The comment directly answers my question. I don't know why it was down-voted. This answer could be applicable to other type-casting situations in TypeScript.